# CLGeocoder error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, reverse-geocoding

I'm using CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation. I get the crash after running for about 5-10 minutes (with no noticeable pattern) and get random crashes. Here's my code:

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        let currentLatCoord = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude
        let currentLongCoord = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currentLatCoord!, longitude: currentLongCoord!)) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark

            placeMark = placeArray![0]

            self.locationLabel.text = String(placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"]!)
        }
    }
```

And also, just to help, here's a picture of the line and error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some optional binding:

```
if let thoroughfare = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? String {
    self.locationLabel.text = thoroughfare
}
```

I'm guessing either there might not be a `"Thoroughfare"` key in the address dictionary, and you're providing a `nil` value to the designated initializer for `String`.

Is there a chance that the view being updated in your code snippet is not on the screen (disposed) when the `CLGeocoder` has finished its reverse geocoding? If you have your outlet defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional:

`@IBOutlet var locationLabel : UILabel!`

I'm wondering if it has already been set to `nil`, but due to the bang (`!`) the compiler isn't making you check.

But, of course, if your view is still on the screen when you crash, this probably isn't the issue.

Comment: It isn't always `nil`. it works for about 4 updates, a lot of the time longer. Eventually though, it crashes. only after some time though. I also tested it, and it seemed to update in a real-life instance, as well as the simulation for a few updates.

Comment: I also just found out I get a very similar error sometimes when the app launches on the line: `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currentLatCoord!, longitude: currentLongCoord!)) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in`

Comment: Sure, but you you need to guard against the cases where it *is* going to be `nil`. Reverse geocoding is not always guaranteed to be precise, nor have the same values every time the callback is executed. And your "very similar error" is likely a case of force unwrapping the `currentLatCoord` and `currentLongCoord`, which are probably `nil`. You should *check before using them* with an `if let` statement.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! So this is how one of them should look for instance?             `var currentLatCoord = Double()
            if manager.location?.coordinate.latitude != nil {
                currentLatCoord = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
            } else {
                currentLatCoord = 0.0
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You provided us a code sample:

```
let currentLatCoord = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude
let currentLongCoord = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currentLatCoord!, longitude: currentLongCoord!)) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
    var placeMark: CLPlacemark

    placeMark = placeArray![0]

    self.locationLabel.text = String(placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"]!)
}
```

You can more gracefully handle `nil` values if you use the `if let` construct:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!) { placemarks, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
        self.locationLabel.text = placemark.thoroughfare
    }
}
```

And, of course, if you're calling this repeatedly, I wouldn't re-instantiate a new `CLGeocoder` every time, but hopefully this illustrates the pattern.

But as you can see, you can avoid extracting the latitude and longitude from the location property to only then create a new `CLLocation` object by simply using `manager.location` directly. Likewise, you can use the `thoroughfare` property, which saves you from needing to cast the `addressDictionary` value.

The key observation, which Craig mentioned above, is to scrupulously avoid using the `!` forced unwrapping operator unless you are positive that the variable can never be `nil`. Likewise, don't use `[0]` syntax unless you know for a fact that there is at least one item in the array (which is why I use `first`, which is an optional for which I can easily test).

Frankly, I'd even make sure that the `location` was valid (not `nil` and with a non-negative `horizontalAccuracy`, as a negative value indicates that the coordinates are not valid):

```
if let location = manager.location where location.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            self.locationLabel.text = placemark.thoroughfare
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I don't want you to unaccept Craig's answer, because he got to the root of the issue. I just wanted to expand on the discussion about writing safe code.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I have the tendency to keep my code junky, I don't know why.